# Powershell | second Invoke Using:Variable

Tags: powershell, variables, invoke, using

i have a simple question. I want to use a variable in an invoke-command and pass this to the second invoke-command. In the second invoke-command the variable is empty

here is my code:,

```
$WaitSeconds = 1234

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remote -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
    $computer = dsquery computer "DC=domain,DC=local" -o rdn 
    $computers = $computer -replace ('"', '') 
    write-host $computers

    foreach ($computer in $computers) {
        if ($computer -notmatch "AZUREADSSOACC")
        {
            Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -Credential $using:cred -ScriptBlock {
                #### here script
                shutdown -s -t $using:waitseconds
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> In the second invoke-command the variable is empty

That's because the variable doesn't exist inside the calling session (the first `Invoke-Command` call's execution context).

Make sure you first instruct PowerShell to copy the variable to the "outer" `Invoke-Command` call:

```
$WaitSeconds = 1234

Invoke-Command {
    # PowerShell will now copy the $WaitSeconds variable value from the calling scope to this remote session
    $WaitSeconds = $using:WaitSeconds

    # ...

    Invoke-Command {
        # This will now resolve the variable value correctly
        shutdown -s -t $using:WaitSeconds
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you, I tried it. But didnt work for me ;(

Answer (score 0):

i got it
my solution is:

```
$WaitSeconds = 1234

Invoke-Command {
param($WaitSeconds)
   
    $WaitSeconds = $WaitSeconds

    # ...

    Invoke-Command {
    param($WaitSeconds)
        
        shutdown -s -t $WaitSeconds
    } -ArgumentList $WaitSeconds

} -ArgumentList $WaitSeconds
```